# Why imported classes take precedence over bundle classes?

Tags: osgi, classloader

I know that the specification exactly defines it but cannot get what is the reason for this:

```
A class space is then all classes reachable from a given bundle’s class loader. 
Thus, a class space for a given bundle can contain classes from:
• The parent class loader (normally java.* packages from the boot class path)
• Imported packages
• Required  bundles
• The bundle's class path (private packages)
• Attached fragments
```

Let's assume:

1. A bundle declares "import-package: a"
2. There is a local class a.X in this bundle
3. There is a class a.X in another bundle

new a.X() would load the class from another bundle.

What is the reason that imported classes take precedence over bundle classes? Is it just a consequent continuation of java hierarchical class loading policy?

Comment: this allow an optional imports modify your behaviour.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is actually a core aspect of OSGi.

### Sharing classes

The whole import/export mechanism is intended to let different bundles use the *same* class when communicating. *Same* in this case means not only binary equal, but *loaded by the same class loader* (recall that every bundle has its own class loader). If the bundle's own classes would be favored over imported ones, bundles would not be able to 'agree' on which copy of a class to use.

### But... why?

Why would you have a copy of a class, which you also intend to import?
Consider a situation in which you want to do some logging, so you import `org.osgi.service.log`, but it's not a vital aspect, you can happily run without a `LogService` present. Now,

- if you would only import the package, your bundle would fail to resolve, and thus fail to start, and
- if you would only include the class, you would never use the other bundle's `LogService` class, so you cannot use the service (this is the agreeing part).

In this situation, you *both* import and include the class, so you can run in either situation, using your own copy when no one else has one, and sharing a copy if someone else does. You can even choose to export your copy, and let the framework decide.

As a sidenote, this is exactly the reason you should (almost) always *import what you export*.

Comment: Correct. Packages are also considered a unit and are not to be split across class loaders. So either the package is imported and completely provided by the exporter or the package is internal to the bundle.

Require-Bundle is different and does support split packages for the abnormal cases where you have no choice in the matter.

Comment: Right, I skipped over split packages on purpose, since the question didn't lead in that direction. But you're right, those are a special consideration.